# How can disable hyperlink (<a href=""></a>) in tinyMCE Preview

Tags: jquery, tinymce-4

I want to disable all links in tinyMCE Preview popup, and also need to remove the heading preview  from the popup box .

I'm using tinyMCE 4X. preview of tinyMCE Content is done by using preview plug in

Code:

```
$("body").delegate("#previewMail", "click", function(event) { 
  $.fancybox({ 
    'transitionIn': 'none', 'transitionOut': 'none', 'titlePosition' : 'inside', 'transitionIn' : 'none', 'transitionOut' : 'none', 'content':tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(), 
  }); 
}); 
$(document).on('click','.fancybox-inner',function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: I'm using tinyMCE 4X. preview of tinyMCE Content is done by using preview plugin

Comment: I am fixed this issue by removing the TinyMCE preview , and now using fancy box for preview.         $("body").delegate("#previewMail", "click", function(event) {
           $.fancybox({
              'transitionIn': 'none',
              'transitionOut': 'none',
              'titlePosition'   : 'inside',
              'transitionIn'    : 'none',
              'transitionOut'   : 'none',
              'content':tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(),
            }); 
        
        });
        $(document).on('click','.fancybox-inner',function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
        });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am fixed this issue by removing the TinyMCE preview , and now using fancy box for preview.

```
$("body").delegate("#previewMail", "click", function(event) {

 $.fancybox({ 
'transitionIn': 'none', 
'transitionOut': 'none',
 'titlePosition' : 'inside', 
'transitionIn' : 'none',
 'transitionOut' : 'none', 
'content':tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(),
 }); 
}); 

$(document).on('click','.fancybox-inner',function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use preventDefault():

```
$('#popup a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

Or, use return false:

```
$('#popup a').click(function(e){
       return false;
    }
```

Comment: Can you check this pls. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747796/how-to-change-link-color-on-tinymce-once-linked-added