# How to change link color on tinymce once linked added?

Tags: jquery, tinymce-4

I've modify my tinymce to add class to anchot tag and changed the color. below is my code

Answer (score 0):

The `link` plugin does not fire any events of its own when you insert a new link.  The list of events the editor does fire are documented here:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/events/#editorevents

You can check to see what events get triggered by an action and then add code to act upon that event just as you have for the `click` event.

The other alternative is to modify the code of the `link` plugin to do what you need - just know that at that point you will need to re-create those modifications each time you update TinyMCE.

Comment: editorEvents does not have any event for link plugin isn't it?  pls advice

Comment: The link plugin itself does not emit any events.

Comment: any other alternative ways ?

Comment: What have you tried to this point?  Why were those solutions not sufficient?